# Why this COUNT() takes that long in PostgreSQL 9.2?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

My table is (there are some other columns):

```
id INTEGER
amount INTEGER
```

There is an index on `amount`. The query is:

```
explain analyze select count(amount) from receipt
```

Output is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=215856.23..215856.23 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=180209.785..180209.787 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_amount on receipt  (cost=0.00..215046.23 rows=1620001 width=4) (actual time=0.109..177443.189 rows=2584317 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 2316761
Total runtime: 180209.868 ms
```

What's going on? Index-only scan is used and it is supposed to optimize the request, as explained [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F). Why it's slow?

Comment: What happens when you use `count(*)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update your statistics via [analyze](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-analyze.html). When you compare estimated rows (1.620.001) with actual rows (2.584.317), you see that your optimizer is doing a bad job.

Comment: You're right, it did help. Why PostgreSQL is not updating its statistics automatically? Shall I run this `ANALYZE receipt` every hour/day myself?

Comment: "In the default PostgreSQL configuration, the autovacuum daemon takes care of automatic analyzing of tables when they are first loaded with data, and as they change throughout regular operation. When autovacuum is disabled, it is a good idea to run ANALYZE periodically, or just after making major changes in the contents of a table".

Answer (score 2):

This particular problem (note that high `heap fetches` count) seems to be described in [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VacuumHeadaches#Visibility_Vacuuming_and_Index-Only_Scan):

> **Visibility Vacuuming and Index-Only Scan Problem:**
>
> As of 9.2, there's a significant benefit to adding pages to the Visibility Map so that
>   index-only scan is enabled. However, this only gets done for pages
>   which were being vacuumed anyway, so pages with no updates or deletes
>   on them don't get set allvisible unless the user calls a manual
>   VACUUM. This makes index-only scan a lot less useful than it could be.